# SQL query works but very slow on large data set?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to make a query that selects courses to take next quarter that you have already taken the prerequisite for. What makes it difficult for me is if there are multiple prerequisites for a course and you have already completed one.

The two tables are Record(Student, Course) and Prerequisite(Course, Prereq)

My query attempt that works but very slow:

```
select r.Student, p.Course 
from Record r, Prerequisite p where r.Course = p.Prereq and p.Course not in
( select Course from (select r.Student, p.Course from Record r, Prerequisite p 
  where r.Course <> p.Prereq) a where a.Student = r.Student);
```

Any help would be great!

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Prerequisite (Course CHAR(32), Prereq CHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE Record (
    Student CHAR(32), 
    Course CHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (Student, Course)
);
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 3', 'Class 1');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 6', 'Class 4');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 4', 'Class 1');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 4', 'Class 3');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 8', 'Class 2');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 8', 'Class 6');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 5', 'Class 2');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 9', 'Class 8');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 7', 'Class 5');
--added Class 10 requires Class 1 and Class 2
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 10', 'Class 1');
INSERT INTO Prerequisite VALUES ('Class 10', 'Class 2');

INSERT INTO Record VALUES ('Bob', 'Class 1');
INSERT INTO Record VALUES ('Jan', 'Class 2');
--Bob Takes both Class 1 and Class 2 thus he can take Class 10
INSERT INTO Record VALUES ('Bob', 'Class 2');
```

So result should be

```
Bob | Class 3
Jan | Class 5
Bob | Class 5
Bob | Class 10
```

edit: small sample data added

edit2: see the comments below for additional details

edit3: Just realized my solution is not working while looking over Mhai's new solution and making a test case that showed it wasn't working, mine didn't work for that case either.

Updated the sample data with a new test case, that is when you have a student that has taken both prerequisites for a class, they should take that class.

Comment: Add some sample data.

Comment: And like always - check the indices and publish the query plan.

Comment: Added the sample data that I use to test the difficult case. I went about it by first solving the case where if there was only one possible prereq by checking if prerequisite.prereq contained any courses in the record.course that students have taken and matching it with the course that has the prereq in prerequisite.class But in the instance that a class had more than one prereq it didn't work.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why class 3 for bob or why 5 for Jan?For 1 you have to take Prereq 3 and 4..

Comment: I then tried look same case but when record.course <> prerequisite.prereq and that gave me the inverse of what I wanted with select Record.student, Prerequisite.course from Record r, Prerequsite p where r.course <> p.prereq; This gave me all the courses but the ones I needed so I just tried to find the inverse of that and I came up with the above query.

Comment: Bob has Class 3 because Bob took Class 1 and Class 1 is a prerequsite course for Class 3 thus he can take Class 3. Jan took Class 2 which is a prerequisite course for Class 5 and Class 8 but Class 8 also has a prerequsite of Class 6 thus Jan can only take Class 5.

Comment: I`ll be back tomorrow on this.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep messing around with it.

Comment: never use implicit joins, very poor practice

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT r.Student, p.Course FROM Record r
JOIN Prerequisite p
ON r.Course = p.Prereq
LEFT JOIN (
     select  r.Student, p.Course FROM Record r
     JOIN Prerequisite p 
     ON p.Prereq<>r.Course)x
ON x.Student = r.Student
WHERE p.Course IS NULL

SELECT  r.Student,p.Course,pp.Prereq FROM Record r
JOIN Prerequisite p
ON r.Course = p.Prereq
JOIN Prerequisite pp
ON
p.Course=pp.Course
GROUP BY p.Course HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

This will find all records with just 1 requirement

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17bd34/162)

Comment: Hmmm this query didn't return any results. After removing the extra comma after r.Student too.

Comment: Mihai that worked for just the sample data I had there but it doesn't work for the new updated sample data above I posted.

Comment: @blue Sorry i racked my brains and coudnt solve it for all possible cases. Somebody more knowledgeable is needed.

Comment: @blue Try a new schema if thats an option:tables coursed,prerequisites and students,this might make life easier.

Comment: @blue or just get another guy with very high reputation and comment on one of his answers if he can come here and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.Student, p.Course 
from Record r inner join Prerequisite p on p.Prereq = r.course where not exists(
( select pr.Course from Prerequisite pr inner join records rr on rr.student=r.student 
where pr.Prereq =r.course ))
```

Try this, use NOLOCK if you afford to have dirty records.

Comment: This didn't return any results for the above sample data too after fixing the typos records to record.